# How expensive is Wwise's SetRTPCValue method?

Tags: audio, wwise

In an ideal world I would have an RTPC value that I could set every frame (as it is time-based and needs to count milliseconds).  Is this an expensive call or should I not sweat it?

```
AKRESULT AK::SoundEngine::SetRTPCValue( 
    const char *    in_pszRtpcName,                                 // Name of the RTPC
    AkRtpcValue     in_value,                                       // Value to set.
    AkGameObjectID  in_gameObjectID = AK_INVALID_GAME_OBJECT        // Associated game object ID
```

);

https://www.audiokinetic.com/library/2015.1.4_5497/?source=SDK&id=soundengine__rtpc.html

Since it may make a difference, I'm using this via a plugin for Unity3D.

Comment: Use a profiler and find out. It used to be a Pro-only feature in Unity, but since 5, it's now available in Personal Edition.

Comment: "Once per frame" updates are almost never worth worrying about. It'd have to be _exceptionally_ slow (and it isn't) to be a problem at once per frame. You've got 16 whole milliseconds. :p

Comment: This is very vague, what do you want? an answer like "12"? Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. It isn't too costly until it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know concretely "how expensive it is" but I do know that you don't need to sweat it. We're calling `SetRTPCValue` more than a few times per frame without trouble; can't even see it on a profile.

You may or may not run into trouble calling it hundreds of times per frame (I don't know), but a handful of times is just fine.

That said, I can't speak authoritatively on the Unity integration, but I'd imagine it's comparable.